# How do I make my Node.js websocket socket.io server more resilient to DoS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My project has a WebSocket server built in Node.js using socket.io.

Reviewing the causes of a recent outage, I found that the front-end app gets into a state where it keeps making malformed connection attempts which the server rejects. It does so in a loop with no back-off.

What ends up happening on this server is that the single Node.js CPU thread ends up getting clogged up with the backlog and it creates a cascading effect -- no new request can be made, no other processing can happen, and so on.

The easy way to fix this is on the client -- figure out why it goes into the rapid-fire loop and add some exponential back-off.

However, this doesn't solve the problem of a similar issue happening in the future. So, I need to find a way to make my server more resilient.

One approach could be to use the `backlog` parameter when calling `server.listen`. That, however, could prevent legitimate client requests from going through.

I'd love to be able to somehow identify an out of control client in some way. IP address might not work well because of NAT, proxies, and firewalls.

So, what would be a good way of protecting my server from this type of DoS?

Comment: Each client has a socket id; use that and a basic array to calculate the average time between requests, and if it drops below a certain threshold, drop the connection.

Comment: 1) reduce your server response time by optimizing it. 2) use javascripts asynchronity to enable multiple connections at once. 3) put a nginx or fail2ban in front.

Comment: My compony use cloudflare to prevent ddos attacks. 
Other things what you can do is scale up the node application, if you have 4 core server, you can run 4 instance of the application and use nginx for load balancing.

Comment: FYI, the behavior you describe where a socket.io client attempts to connect, fails, than tries again over and over is what happens when you have mismatched client and server versions of socket.io.  I know this isn't an answer to the generic question about DOS attacks, but it may help you debug that particular issue.  This is a really unfortunate side effect of the most recent major version increase with socket.io.  Older clients are really badly behaved with the new server version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal place to intercept a DoS attack is BEFORE the connection gets to your application server.  That would typically be in a router, firewall or load balancer and you'd rely on the means that it has for rate limiting from a particular source.  If you are paying for a hosting service, this should be one of the features the hosting service has to offer as many of the larger or more visible tenants will want that type of service.

From an accidentally misbehaved browser (like you describe in your question), you can cookie a request that has been denied and then rate limit any client that presents that cookie (limit them to no more than N connection requests/minute).

You cannot rely on a cookie for an actual purposeful DoS attack since attackers probably won't preserve cookies if it interferes with their attack.  For that, all any infrastructure can do is to look for identifying information in the source (which is typically the IP address).  If you accidentally sweep up a few legitimate clients who happen to be sharing the same NAT or proxy (and thus get identified as the same IP address as where a DoS attack is coming from), then that's just the nature of the problem.  There isn't much you can do about that.  You have to protect the integrity of the service at all cost and there really isn't much else you can do if cookies aren't being preserved by a real attacker.

If you choose to try to implement this type of protection yourself, then you can either try implementing it in your application server (and accept some performance hit for doing so) or you can deploy an intermediary on your same host such as NGINX to serve as mitigation for DoS attacks.  Here's an article on using NGINX for that: [Mitigating DDoS Attacks with NGINX and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/).